# Xcode open specific view with push notifications in storyboard

Tags: objective-c, xcode, storyboard, push-notification, uitabbarcontroller

In my codes, I wrote it in this way

```
DetailView *vc = (DetailView *)[mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DetailVC"];

self.window.rootViewController = vc;
```

It only show that view but I don't see the navigational bar and tab bar.

What is the right way to open a specific view (inside tabbarcontroller) within storyboard when the app receive remote notifications automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you get only `DetailView` from storyboard. If you want to show it inside navigation controller you have to init this controller.

```
DetailView *vc = (DetailView *)[mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DetailVC"];
UINavigationController *navVC = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: vc];
self.window.rootViewController = navVC;
```

But I think the issue is in other. You instantiate wrong view controller. You should instantiate tab bar controller or navigation controller and then only select proper tab.

Comment: Let's say I have three view controllers, Do I have to instantiate them and add it all inside the tab bar controller?

Comment: Do you have tab bar controller inside storyboard?

Comment: Yes I have that controller.

Comment: You should instantiate tab bar controller. And select proper controller.

Comment: Do I have to set the Identifier of that tab bar controller so I could instantiate it?

Comment: If it is not initial controller than yes. If it is you can just instantiate initial controller.

Comment: It's not my initial controller, so I have to set the identifier on it. I will try what I learn from you.